# Check is tabular model has loaded latest data

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx, xmla, ssas-tabular

We've a few tabular models on 2012 server. We have queries running to find if the processing of these was successful and that's about it.

Most of the times processing is successful but it does not have the latest data.

Can I run some MDX XMLA to know if the data loaded is the latest data.

Thank you

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti It worked but please confrim as per below question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using DMV**

```
SELECT TOP 1 [LAST_DATA_UPDATE]FROM $System.MDSCHEMA_CUBESWHERE [catalog_name] = 'AdventureWorks Tabular Model SQL 2012'ORDER BY [LAST_DATA_UPDATE] DESC
```

**Using XMLA**

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">    <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_CUBES</RequestType>    <Restrictions/>    <Properties>        <PropertyList>            <Catalog>YourCubeDatabaseName</Catalog>        </PropertyList>    </Properties></Discover>
```

Here the `LAST_DATA_UPDATE` tag in the result contains the information about the last full process on the entire database.

Comment: that looks great and it feels right, but can you confirm if that is the latest data it has or it is the latest date it was processed.

Comment: If a cube is full processed, it automatically implies that it has the latest data. There are some other processing options as well like Process Add, Process Update which might  or might not pull latest data.